# Calculating length of triangle sides in trapezium

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

My younger brother has this mathematical problem to solve, and he came to me for help. At first I thought I could solve it by simply applying the Pythagorean theorem, but there seems to be more to it.

He mentioned the Thales theorem, which I had to do some research on (it's been almost 7 years ago for me now), but I don't see how it would apply here.

[this is a drawing of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KajCx.png)

Any help or hints about the first step here would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the trapezoid is isosceles, we can break it up like so.

[image]

And now you can use the Pythagorean theorm.

$8^2 + h^2 = (4\sqrt 5)^2$

Comment: Thank you very much!
That was exactly what I was looking for.